# Enable Overscroll even if the ScrollView wasn`t scrolled

Tags: android, scrollview

Sometimes my ScrollView hasn't enough content to be scrolled. Now I want the Overscroll animation enabled even when nothing was scrolled- to tell my users its the end of the page.

`android:overScrollMode="always"` does nothing...

My layout xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:overScrollMode="always">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/event1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@mipmap/event_back1">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/koteret1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_above="@+id/kav1"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:text="Title"
                android:textSize="40dp" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/kav1"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_above="@+id/date1"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:background="#FFFFFF" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/date1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:text="date"
                android:textColor="@color/accent_material_light"
                android:textSize="30dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/time1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/date1"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:text="time"
                android:textColor="@color/accent_material_light"
                android:textSize="30dp" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/event2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@mipmap/event_back2">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/koteret2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_above="@+id/kav2"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:text="Title"
                android:textSize="40dp" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/kav2"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_above="@+id/date2"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:background="#FFFFFF" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/date2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:text="date"
                android:textColor="@color/accent_material_light"
                android:textSize="30dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/time2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/date2"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:text="time"
                android:textColor="@color/accent_material_light"
                android:textSize="30dp" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/event3"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@mipmap/event_back3">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/koteret3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_above="@+id/kav3"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:text="Title"
                android:textSize="40dp" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/kav3"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_above="@+id/date3"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:background="#FFFFFF" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/date3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:text="date"
                android:textColor="@color/accent_material_light"
                android:textSize="30dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/time3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/date3"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:text="time"
                android:textColor="@color/accent_material_light"
                android:textSize="30dp" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

and it looks like this:

[image]

Please notice I want it exactly like this and not in ListView.

Thank you :)

Comment: can you post your layout code?

Comment: posted. please check it.

Comment: I had run this layout in my device and its working fine. The overscroll mode is showing.

Comment: The Onclicklistener on every RelativeLayout is blocking the overscrolling. Any ideas how to solve this?